# Liquibase constraint for unique value in selected fields in one record

Tags: liquibase

I need to create some kind of constraint to disallow inserting identical values in one record. Like for example there is an entity **GradientBaloon** with fields **TopColor**, **MiddleColor**, **BottomColor** and none of these field can have same value as other. Gradient can be *Red, Blue, Green,* but not *Red, Red, Blue*. But it's not like regular unique constraint to be compared with other records of the same kind in database.

How do I achieve it in liquibase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check constraint on all the 3 columns (`TopColor`, `MiddleColor` and `BottomColor`) to ensure that they aren't the same value:

```
changeSet:  
  id:  ...
  author:  ...  
  changes:  
  -  addCheckConstraint:  
      constraintBody:  TopColor <> MiddleColor <> BottomColor    
      constraintName:  someName
      tableName:  GradientBaloon 
      validate:  true
```

Which will be translated to the following SQL which can be included in the `sql` part in the [changeSet](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html):

`ALTER TABLE GradientBaloon ADD CONSTRAINT TopColor CHECK (TopColor <> MiddleColor <> BottomColor);`

Comment: `addCheckConstraint` is only available in PRO edition. I don't have PRO edition.

Comment: In this case you can include the plain SQL in your changeSet - link is attached in the post